# Using NSToolbar in Storyboard to build a Preference Panel through Triggered Segues

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, storyboard, interface-builder

I try to use Storyboard to link an NSToolbar to different View Controller through Triggered Segues. I want them all to be opened in the same Window Controller. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Clicking on each NSToolbarItem opens a new window instead of the same Window Controller. Any idea how this can be done without coding?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkCuu.png)

Basically, what you need to do is to just use an NSTabViewController - Set it and your window content and also select what style you want your toolbar to have! See image.

Comment: So what is the NSToolbar for?

Comment: Oh and thanks! It worked as advertised. I still wonder how NSToolbar works since it is more modular than the tabview

Comment: http://www.extelligentcocoa.org/toolbar-tutorial/ probably has more about NSToolbar than you ever wanted to know ;-)